# Why does this image shrink in Oreo and above?

Tags: android

Image link:(in android ver 8)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdZRg.jpg

(in android version 7 and below)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4eca.png

I have just added imageview and nothing else why is there difference in both Android different version

```
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/abc"/>
```

Comment: Share your xml with us

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageView` is set to `120dp` in height and your screenshots seem to be taken from different devices. It is likely that these devices have different dpi and screen size and you ImageView is always set to defined size.

If you need your ImageView to look the same on different screen sizes then what you could try is set `android:scaleType` parameter with `fitCenter` or something like that.